# How to display more than one line in UIMenuItem?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I'm trying to display more than one line of text in a custom UIMenuItem.
I've tried using a simple "\n" in the title property of the UIMenuItem but with no luck.
Example:

```
UIMenuItem *menuItem; //Is then allocated properly....

// Before the Menu is displayed
menuItem.title = @"This is a first line.\nThis is a second line.";
```

Unfortunately I just end up with one line being displayed...

What I want to achieve is something similar to what you can see upon a LongPress on a row in the Apple iPod/Music app.

[image: Multi-line UIMenuItem in iPod app]

I've just found out about this github project as a solution:
https://github.com/questbeat/QBPopupMenu

You can display whatever custom UIView within a MenuItem. So I inserted a multi-line UILabel and that works.

However I would rather use the native Apple UIMenutItem approach if this is possible. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change some internal property of the `UIMenuItem`, but unfortunately Apple does not provide a way to do it.

So, as for today, there's not way to change the display of a `UIMenuItem`.

Comment: Thanks for your your answer Gabriele! I guess we'll have to wait until iOS 7.0 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried '\r' instead of '\n'?

Comment: iOS is Unix-based, so `\n` is used for new lines